# spring Boot + JPA + Hibernate+ crud Operation

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/hibernate/SessionFactory has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/hibernate/SessionFactory has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Unsupported major.minor version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-unsupported-major-minor-versi)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using java 1.8 but the hibernate jar is java v 11. Either you must use a much older version of hibernate or use java 11